# GroupBy on multiple properties with complex type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have written a GroupBy statement like so:

```
var aggregated = sitesWithLive
    .GroupBy(s => new {s.SiteRefNum, s.SiteRefName, s.Address})
    .Select(g =>
        new Site
        {
            SiteRefNum = g.Key.SiteRefNum,
            SiteRefName = g.Key.SiteRefName,
            Address = g.Key.Address,
            ContractLive = g.Max(x => x.ContractLive)
        });
```

In the grouping is `Address` which is a complex type:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string Line4 { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(a => a.GetValue(this) is string)
            .Select(a => (string)a.GetValue(this))
            .All(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var addr = Line1 + "," + Line2 + "," + Line3 + "," + Line4 + "," + PostCode;
        var address = Regex.Replace(addr, @"^,+|,{2,}|,(?=[\w.])", ", ");
        return address;
    }
}
```

However this does not correctly group by address, instead returning a separate group for each element.

It was my understanding that to group by the complex type you must provide an `IEqualityComparer` so I created the following:

```
public class AddressComparer : IEqualityComparer<Address>
{
    public bool Equals(Address x, Address y)
    {
        return x.ToString() == y.ToString();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Address obj)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and supplied it like so (subset of above):

```
var aggregated = sitesWithLive.GroupBy(s => new {s.SiteRefNum, s.SiteRefName, s.Address}, new AddressComparer())
...
```

This however gives me

> The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying
>   the type arguments explicitly.

I'm at a loss as to my next step, surely this sort of grouping shouldn't be too difficult?

Comment: Omg, what the hell is happening inside ToString(). Why you need regex here? Isn't it better to build correct string from begining? Also, you returning 1 in GetHashCode which is correct but very inefficient.

Comment: @eocron: That's not  really for you to judge, really - maybe he's normalizing some address data that comes from a third party? It would be instead be better to suggest an alternative way to compare the objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Enumerable.GroupBy` allows you to pass custom equality comparer for keys. But in your case key is not an `Address` object - it's an anonymous object containing three properties - `SiteRefNum`, `SiteRefName` and `Address`. Of course passing `AddressComparer` to compare such keys will cause an error.

And your first problem was using complex object as key property. If you don't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods for `Address` objects, then all addresses will be compared by reference. Which is of course different for each address instance. You can provide `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations to compare addresses.

Or you can modify your query to use address string for grouping:

```
var aggregated = 
    from s in sitesWithLive
    group s by new {
       s.SiteRefNum,
       s.SiteRefName,
       Address = s.Address.ToString() // here we group by string
    } into g
    select new Site
    {
        SiteRefNum = g.Key.SiteRefNum,
        SiteRefName = g.Key.SiteRefName,
        Address = g.First().Address, // here we just get first address object
        ContractLive = g.Max(x => x.ContractLive)
    };
```

You can use method syntax for query, but I find declarative query syntax more readable :)

Comment: The explanation as to why it doesn't currently work is nice - but I think the thing that is important here is that `Address` needs to have a Equals and GetHashCode implementation and that kinda gets lost here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to override Equals and GetHashCode in your Address class (like in your comparer):

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Address adr = obj as Address;
    if (adr != null)
        return adr.ToString() == this.ToString();
    return false;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.ToString().GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Note - you should always override `GetHashCode` as well

Comment: just noticed it ... i forget GetHashCode